# How to get the Div width including the scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to get the div inner width including the scroll.

I tried `$('.element').width();` function, but this returns the width on the div without scroll.

How to get the width including the scroll ?

Comment: @Mehar normally it's 17px

Answer (score 6):

The Element.scrollWidth read–only property returns either the width in pixels of the content of an element or the width of the element itself, whichever is greater. If the element is wider than its content area (for example, if there are scroll bars for scrolling through the content), the scrollWidth is larger than the clientWidth.

```
$('.element')[0].scrollWidth  ?
```

Comment: Only answer that returns the width including scroll

Answer (score 0):

The jquery `width()` function returns width including the scroll. You can test it:

http://jsfiddle.net/gc6wvj0v/1

In this case:

```
 $('.over').outerWidth() === $('.over').width() // true
```

If you have a ruler (I have one in my firefox) the width is exactly the box + the scroll.
Are you sure that scroll is not returned?

Comment: This is true, this works, it has a fiddle to test it. Div with and without scroll has a width of 200px. what are wrong? what about downvote fast-finger-users ?

Comment: I think the point is that the scroll is meant to be on the horizontal in which case your answer would not give the correct width including the scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/gc6wvj0v/2/

Answer (score -1):

Return the inner width of the element:

```
$('.element').innerWidth();
```

Comment: Isn't this the opposite of what the question is asking for?